# java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid code -- missing end-of-block --> while calling ZipInputStream.closeEntry()

Tags: java

While calling the coseEntry() on ZipInputStream ,it is causing -->java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid code -- missing end-of-block

```
private byte[] updateWithNewTraffic(ZipInputStream TrafficZipIn, String action){
    byte[] ByteArr = null;`enter code here`
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream OutByteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ZipOutputStream zipOut = new ZipOutputStream(OutByteStream);
        HashSet<String> files = new HashSet<String>();

        ZipEntry  entry = TrafficZipIn.getNextEntry();
        while (entry != null) {
            String filename = entry.getName();
            if (FilenameUtils.getExtension(filename.toLowerCase()).equals("txt") {
                zipOut.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(fileName));
                writeInToOutStream(TrafficZipIn,zipOut );
                zipOut.closeEntry();
            }
            TrafficZipIn.closeEntry();---->getting exception in this line
            entry = TrafficZipIn.getNextEntry();
        }
        TrafficZipIn.close();
        zipOut.close();
        ByteArr = OutByteStream.toByteArray();
        OutByteStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //Getting exception.
    }
    return ByteArr;
}
private void writeInToOutStream(InputStream in, OutputStream out) {
    try {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //Failed writing to stream
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you paste the complete code.?

Comment: "missing end-of-block" means that the zip file is incomplete. If it was created by Java code, it likely means that the code creating the file forgot to `close()` or `finish()` the output stream.

Answer (score 0):

If you had a `maven` project, consider including this section in `pom.xml`.

Maven can corrupt those files during the resources filtering in project's compilation.

Read: [Maven resources plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html)

```xml
    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.xls</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/*.xlsx</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.xls</include>
                    <include>**/*.xlsx</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>

...
```